# Chaining (Dependency) Properties to nested control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` with a `GroupStyle` that contains another ListBox. 
Now I want to filter the Items of the nested ListBox depending on the group name of the parent ListBox.

In the code below I tried to chain the `GroupItem.Name.Name` property to the `GroupName` property of the ViewModel of the nested ListBox, but this didn't work out so well.

Essentially the `GroupNameIn` Property is filled by the GroupItems' name(the TextBlock Text) and then sets the `GroupNameOut` Property to the same value in the `PropertyChangedCallback`. But the problem is that the `GroupName` Property of the `NestedItemsViewModel` to which `GroupNameOut` is bound to doesn't update.

Are there some mistakes in my approach or is there even a simpler/better way to achieve this behavior?

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

*GroupStyle of the parent ListBox:*

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxGroupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <StackPanel Name="container" Width="Auto" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Name="groupNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Name.Name}"/>

                    <ItemsPresenter/>

                    <MyNestedListBox  
                          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=NestedItemsDataContext}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding NestedItems}"
                          GroupNameIn="{Binding ElementName=groupNameTextBlock, Path=Text}"
                          GroupNameOut="{Binding Path=GroupName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*The nested ListBox:*

```
public class MyNestedListBox : ListBox
{
    static MyNestedListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyNestedListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyNestedListBox)));
    }

    public string GroupNameIn
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(GroupNameInProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GroupNameInProperty, value); }
    }
    public string GroupNameOut
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(GroupNameOutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GroupNameOutProperty, value); }
    }

    // DepenencyProperties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameInProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GroupNameIn", typeof(string), typeof(MyNestedListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null) { PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, target) => 
            {
                obj.SetValue(GroupNameOutProperty, target.NewValue);
            } 
        });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameOutProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GroupNameOut", typeof(string), typeof(MyNestedListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

*ViewModel bound to the nested ListBox:*

```
public class NestedItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _groupName;

    public ObservableCollection<NestedItem> NestedItems { get; set; }
    public string GroupName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _groupName;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => GroupName);
        }
    }

    public NestedItemsViewModel()
    {
        NestedItems = new ObservableCollection<NestedItem>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are binding DataContext of the inner ListBox to the property "NestedItemsDataContext" of the parent ListBox by RelativeSource. But ListBox does not contain property with that name, where is the "NestedItemsDataContext" declared?

Comment: It is declared as a Dependency Property of the parent ListBox.